# How can I add a 3rd party dependency in a custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, composer, 3rd-party-library

I'm building a module which requires a 3rd party library, how can I make the 3rd party library available to the module without without adding it to the composer.json magento root file?

I added it into the composer.json file in the module directory, but running `composer update` from the magento root, is not downloading it.
The module is enabled.

------ UPDATE ---------

Just in case is needed, here the content of the composer.json file inside the module directory.

```
{
  "name": "myVendor/myModule",
  "description": "Module Description",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "extra": {
      "map": [
          ["*",
              "MyVendor/MyModule"
          ]
      ]
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-catalog": "~100.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "MyVendor\\MyModule\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```